# JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, java-11, javafx-11

I'm using Java 11 and JavaFx-11 to create an FX application with IntelliJ IDEA...i have brought in all the external libraries i need. When i run the application, i get the following error, "Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application"...the program compiles properly without any syntax error or anything..its just that one error.

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I solved it, in the src folder right click then follow New > model-info.java
Then in this file, add the following lines of code:

requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;

    opens sample;

Answer (score -1):

I think we have the same problems. last time I use my JDK 11, I couldn't find java fx library there. then I check in any website, JavaFX is no longer included in JDK 11. check it : https://www.infoworld.com/article/3305073/removed-from-jdk-11-javafx-11-arrives-as-a-standalone-module.html